# Issues with DHCP configuration on Ubuntu Server LTS 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dhcp, tftp

I am currently setting up a machine that has two interfaces. One of the interfaces connects to the internet, and the other connects to a switch that manages a local network via DHCP.

The DHCP server is leasing out IP addresses correctly, but the machines themselves cannot ping machines outside of the local network. Neither via DNS name nor IP Address.

I have enabled IPv4 forwarding in the systemctl file, so I am not sure what else I could be missing. I am not too familiar with setting this kind of stuff up on linux so I was wondering if I could get some help. It seems like I am still missing something. Below is my dhcpd.conf file.

Note: This server is also going to be a TFTP server, which is why I have all the extra stuff in this file

```
option space PXE;
option PXE.mtftp-ip code 1 = ip-address;
option PXE.mtftp-cport code 2 = unsigned integer 16;
option PXE.mtftp-sport code 3 = unsigned integer 16;
option PXE.mtftp-tmout code 4 = unsigned integer 8;
option PXE.mtftp-delay code 5 = unsigned integer 8;

option arch code 93 = unsigned integer 16;
use-host-decl-names on;
ddns-update-style interim;
ignore client-updates;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com";
option domain-name-servers ###.###.12.30,###.###.12.8;

# Specify subnet of ether device you do NOT want service.
# For systems with two or more ethernet devices.
# subnet 136.165.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {}
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    range dynamic-bootp 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    default-lease-time 21600;
    max-lease-time 43200;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    next-server 192.168.1.3;
    include "/etc/dhcp/worker-reservations.conf";
    class "Legacy" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 20) = "PXEClient:Arch:00000";
        filename "undionly.kkpxe";
    }
    class "UEFI-32-2" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 20) = "PXEClient:Arch:00002";
        filename "i386-efi/ipxe.efi";
    }
    class "UEFI-32-1" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 20) = "PXEClient:Arch:00006";
        filename "i386-efi/ipxe.efi";
    }
    class "UEFI-64-1" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 20) = "PXEClient:Arch:00007";
        filename "ipxe.efi";
    }
    class "UEFI-64-2" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 20) = "PXEClient:Arch:00008";
        filename "ipxe.efi";
    }
    class "UEFI-64-3" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 20) = "PXEClient:Arch:00009";
        filename "ipxe.efi";
    }
    class "SURFACE-PRO-4" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 32) = "PXEClient:Arch:00007:UNDI:003016";
        filename "ipxe7156.efi";
    }
    class "Apple-Intel-Netboot" {
        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 14) = "AAPLBSDPC/i386";
        option dhcp-parameter-request-list 1,3,17,43,60;
        if (option dhcp-message-type = 8) {
            option vendor-class-identifier "AAPLBSDPC";
            if (substring(option vendor-encapsulated-options, 0, 3) = 01:01:01) {
                # BSDP List
                option vendor-encapsulated-options 01:01:01:04:02:80:00:07:04:81:00:05:2a:09:0D:81:00:05:2a:08:69:50:58:45:2d:46:4f:47;
                filename "ipxe.efi";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And on top of enabling forwarding you'll have to set up iptables for NATing.

Comment: Just a sanity check: The DHCP server is running on `192.168.1.1`?